# How to assign a NULL value with a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to assign a NULL value when another field is NULL using a CASE statement.

So far this is what I got:

```
UPDATE PunchintervalFinal
SET    INDTTIME_LUNCH = (SELECT CASE
                                  WHEN PunchintervalFinal.INDTTIME2 IS NULL THEN
                                  NULL
                                END
                         FROM   PUNCHBRIDGE A
                         WHERE  A.EMPLOYEE = PunchintervalFinal.EMPLOYEE
                                AND A.PUNCHDATE = PunchintervalFinal.PUNCHDATE
                                AND PunchintervalFinal.EMPLOYEE = '500018')
```

Comment: There is a button named **"Caps Lock"** please turn it off...

Comment: Having all caps is like screaming on the Internet. Edit your question and make it readable. Also make sure to format your code as code (the `{}` button above the editor). Readable questions have a much higher chance of getting answers.

Comment: And what do you want if `PunchintervalFinal.INDTTIME2` is NOT NULL?

Comment: For those who are not null leave them the way they are

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you are trying to do:

```
UPDATE PunchintervalFinal
SET    INDTTIME_LUNCH = NULL
FROM PunchintervalFinal
     INNER JOIN PUNCHBRIDGE A ON A.EMPLOYEE = PunchintervalFinal.EMPLOYEE
WHERE PunchintervalFinal.EMPLOYEE = '500018' 
  AND A.PUNCHDATE = PunchintervalFinal.PUNCHDATE
  AND PunchintervalFinal.INDTTIME2 IS NULL
```

Comment: @JorgeVillatoro Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct for future reference